# Is there a better way to code this Duplicate ID Checker?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

First of all, sorry for the bad English, it isn't my main language. Second, I don't know if this belongs here or in Code Review.

---

Basically, this method asks for the Inventory (`List<Product>`) where the object is, and the `Int32` value for the `Product` ID.
Then, it checks if the `Product` ID is already present in said inventory, and if it is, the function searches for the lowest `Int32` value available for the ID.
The advantage of this method is that no ID numbers go to waste, but I'd like to hear some opinions on how I can improve it...

```
if (inventory.Products.Where(x => x.ID == id).Any())
{
    idChanged = true;
    bool towardsNegative = true;

    while (inventory.Products.Where(x => x.ID == id).Any())
    {
        if(id < 0 && towardsNegative)
        {
            towardsNegative = false;
            id++;
        }

        if(towardsNegative)
        {
            id--;
        }
        else
        {
            id++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a simple List, use some sorted collection where the elements would be sorted by product ID. Then you could use the well-known divide-and-conquer algorithm to efficiently search for "holes" in the sequence of sorted product IDs. But an even better approach is to not worry  and not do this unless it really would be necessary. Maintain the currently highest used product ID in use (which would be the last product ID in the sorted sequence of used product IDs). Whenever you need a new product ID, use the previously highest product ID + 1 until you reach int.MaxValue. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) If you have reached int.MaxValue, use the aforementioned divide-and-conquer method to find holes/unused IDs in your sorted product ID sequence. There is no need to spend CPU cycles searching for unused ID's within the used product ID set while you could simply grab unused IDs "from the top"...

Comment: @elgonzo That's a valid point, I shouldn't worry every time about ID's being in order, and if I happen to reach the int.MaxValue (unlikely), I could use the unused ID's. By the way, does this "divide-and-conquer" algorithm has a specific name?

Comment: Yes, the name of the "divide-and-conquer" algorithm is (...drumroll...) "[divide-and-conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm)". I am terribly sorry for my bad attempt at humor ;-) If you don't feel comfortable with or have no prior experience with variants of this algorithm, you could of course stick with a linear search through your used product IDs to find holes/unused IDs. As long as you only have a few hundred products (or maybe even a few thousand), the performance impact of linear searching would perhaps not be that significant, i guess...

Comment: Edit to my former comment; the last sentence should be: As long as you only have a few hundred products (or maybe even a few thousand) to search _until an unused ID is found_, the performance impact of linear searching would perhaps not be that significant, i guess...

Comment: If this code has to deal with concurrent requests attempting to find a "free" id, you're going to get into trouble with race conditions.

Comment: Plus instead of inventory.Products.Where(x => x.ID == id).Any()... You could just do... inventory.Products.Any(x => x.ID == id)

Comment: @elgonzo Actually, I laughed for 30 secs non-stop, wasn't expecting it. But really, I'll study more about this algorithm.

Comment: As you rightly guessed, this question appears to belong on another Stack Exchange site dedicated to _code review_.  Please ensure you read the relevant FAQ before cross-posting.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
var data =  inventory.Products.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList()
```

In this data, results give only duplicate records.

For Example

```
public class Friend
{
  public int id { get; set; }
}
 List<Friend> lst = new List<Friend>();
            lst.Add(new Friend{ id = 1});
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 1 });
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 2 });
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 3 });
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 3 });
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 4 });
var data1 = lst.GroupBy(x => x.id).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: I am so sorry for the wait. For all this time I didn't take my time to understand this code. Now that I was trying to "compile" this on my mind, it seems like the perfect solution. Thanks for the answer. +1